# python regex trouble

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code :

```
what = re.match("get|post|put|head\s+(\S+) ",data,re.IGNORECASE)
```

and in the **data** variable let's say I have this line :

```
GET some-site.com HTTP/1.0 ...
```

If I stop the script in the debugger, and inspect the **what** variable, I can see it only matched GET. Why doesn't it match some-site.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> re.match("(get|post|put|head)\s+(\S+) ",'GET some-site.com HTTP/1.0 ...',re.IGNORECASE).groups()
('GET', 'some-site.com')
>>>
```

Comment: It works, but can you please explain why my version doesn't work? I only want to capture the second word. I know I can access it by calling .group(1), but I'm puzzled as to why my version didn't work.

Comment: "Why 1+2+3+4*100 is 406 and not 1000"? http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/regex.html#SECTION000510000000000000000 . Read about the "|" character and its precedence.

Answer (score 4):

Regex language operator precedence puts `head\s+(\S+)` as the 4th alternative. The parenthesis in *@Mykola Kharechko*'s answer arrange for `head` as the 4th alternative, and `\s+(\S+)` is appended to whatever alternative matched the group.

Answer (score 1):

+1 Mykola's answer and gimel's explanation. In addition, do you really want to use regex for this? As you've found out, they are not as straightforward as they look. Here's a non-regex-based method:

```
def splitandpad(s, find, limit):
    seq= s.split(find, limit)
    return seq+['']*(limit-len(seq)+1)

method, path, protocol= splitandpad(data, ' ', 2)
if method.lower() not in ('get', 'head', 'post', 'put'):
    # complain, unknown method
if protocol.lower() not in ('http/1.0', 'http/1.1'):
    # complain, unknown protocol
```

Comment: Yeah,I know I could have used split. I started with a regex, and then got angry that it didn't work :)